# How to catch the all objects with date 5 days from today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I am trying to do this using this scope:

```
>> Job.last.application_date
  Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1
=> Wed, 13 Feb 2013
>> Date.today + 5.days
=> Wed, 13 Feb 2013
>> Job.where(application_date: Date.today + 5.days)
  Job Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."application_date" = '2013-02-13' ORDER BY created_at DESC
=> []
```

*UPDATE*

Hmm, that is not working, maybe because some data format.

```
>> Job.where("application_date = ?", Date.today + 5)
Job Load (0.3ms) SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE (application_date = '2013-02-13') ORDER BY created_at DESC => [] 
>> Job.last.application_date Job Load (0.7ms)
 SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1 => Wed, 13 Feb 2013

# Schema jobs
#  application_date       :date
```

Comment: This will give some result I guess: `Job.where("application_date = ?", Job.last.application_date)`

Comment: Hmmm, somethings is wrong. https://gist.github.com/regedarek/4741515

Comment: Try this: `Job.where(application_date: (Date.today + 5.days).strftime)` .. `(Date.today + 5.days).strftime  #=> "2013-02-14"`

Comment: :| I dont understand still the same problem: https://gist.github.com/regedarek/4741515 Could be related that first I changed application_date using: ``Job.last.update_column :application_date, Date.today + 5.days`` ??

Comment: Have you checked the DB ?? What it is storing?? `SELECT application_date FROM "jobs";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
where("application_date = ?", Date.today + 5)
```

Comment: It's almost always better to use `x BETWEEN ? AND ?` instead of `x >= ? AND x <= y`.

Comment: I want to take Jobs with application date equals 5 days from now not between today and 5 days from now

Comment: Then `Date.today + 5` will give you the date 5 days hence. Use that in your query.